# C# TextBox Line Spacing

Tags: c#, formatting, textbox

I'm working on a plugin for [`Paint.net`](http://getpaint.net) that converts the current image to ASCII art. I have the conversion working fine, and it outputs the ASCII art into a `TextBox` control, with a fixed width font. My problem is, the ASCII art is stretched vertically, because of the line spacing in a TextBox. Is there any way to set the line spacing of a `TextBox`?

Comment: Perhaps use a RichTextBox and set the line height : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/8781caf6-5759-4fee-8c08-cd8a2d85fc9f ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TextBox simply shows single or multiline text with no formatting options - it can have a font but that applies to the TextBox and not to the text, so you can't have paragraph settings like line spacing as far as I know.

My first suggestion would be to use a RichTextBox, but then again, RTF doesn't have a code for line spacing so I believe that would be impossible as well.

So my final suggestions is to use an owner-drawn control. It shouldn't be too difficult with a fixed-width font - you know the location of each character is `(x*w, y*h)` where `x` and `y` are the character index and `w` and `h` are the size of one character.

*Edit:* Thinking about it a bit more, it's even simpler - simply separate the string to lines and draw each line.

---

Here's a simple control that does just that. When testing it I found that for `Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 10, FontStyle.Regular)`, the best value for `Spacing` was `-9`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays text allowing you to control the line spacing
/// </summary>
public class SpacedLabel : Control {
    private string[] parts;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.Clear(BackColor);

        float lineHeight = g.MeasureString("X", Font).Height;

        lineHeight += Spacing;

        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++) {
                g.DrawString(parts[i], Font, brush, 0, i * lineHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string Text {
        get {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set {
            base.Text = value;
            parts = (value ?? "").Replace("\r", "").Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Controls the change in spacing between lines.
    /// </summary>
    public float Spacing { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically by setting the property via [Block class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block):

```
TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
tbox.SetValue(Block.LineHeightProperty, 10.0);
```

Or, if you wanted to do this in Xaml:

```
<TextBox Block.LineHeight="10" />
```